# How many cores in my GPU?

Tags: directx, gpu, gpgpu

How can you tell how many cores are available in any given GPU?
I would prefer a Windows/UI based answer, but API (DirectX?) is also nice to know.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57998/hardware-questions-and-stack-exchange

Comment: I am asking for the API approach. Hence the software question.

Comment: You probably need to provide more details then. At the very least, Nvidia, AMD/ATI, and Intel (and any other GPU manufacturers) all probably have different APIs that relate this information in different ways.

Comment: I was hopping for some cross-driver DirectX API. Stock drivers on my Intel HD Graphics 4000 do not list this type of information.

Comment: You might want to include the fact that you are asking about the DirectX API in your question then, and tag it with the DirectX tag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No such API. Even term "core", applied to graphics hardware cannot be defined in a universal way: different vendors have very different architectures (even on desktop platforms). So, we can have 384 "CUDA cores" in nVidia GPU, 1024 "shader ALUs" in AMD GPU and 20 "blocks" in Intel GPU of the same price/performance/transistor count category. Sometimes you don't even have a dedicated GPU. So, it does not make sense to compare those numbers.

Comment: 1 "core" can be defined as = 1 batch of cores  = 1 set of concurrent SIMD. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/q/10460742/632951

Comment: @Pacerier Well, then "CUDA cores" from Nvidia are not the same as your proposed "cores". A concurrent SIMD block maps well to a "warp" in CUDA programming model. Nvidia marketing department further multiplies the number of SIMD blocks by their width, and, voila, over 5000+ Coarz! So which ones are the real cores now? Also we are not talking here about either CUDA or nVidia. The question is specifically about DirectX.