# Understanding and optimising threads, blocks, and grids in pyCUDA

Tags: python, parallel-processing, cuda, gpu, pycuda

I'm very new to GPU programming and pyCUDA and have a pretty fundamental gap in my knowledge. I have spent quite a bit of time searching SO, looking at example code and reading supporting documentation for CUDA/pyCUDA but haven't found much diversity in the explanations and can't get my head around a few things.

I am having trouble correctly defining block and grid dimensions. The code I am currently running is as follows, and aims to do element-wise multiplication of an array `a` by a float `b`:

```
from __future__ import division
import pycuda.gpuarray as gpuarray
import pycuda.driver as cuda
import pycuda.autoinit
from pycuda.compiler import SourceModule
import numpy as np

rows = 256
cols = 10
a = np.ones((rows, cols), dtype=np.float32)
a_gpu = cuda.mem_alloc(a.nbytes)
cuda.memcpy_htod(a_gpu, a)

b = np.float32(2)

mod = SourceModule("""
  __global__ void MatMult(float *a, float b)
  {
    const int i = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x * blockIdx.x;
    const int j = threadIdx.y + blockDim.y * blockIdx.y;
    int Idx = i + j*gridDim.x;
    a[Idx] *= b;
  }
  """)

func = mod.get_function("MatMult")

xBlock = np.int32(np.floor(1024/rows))
yBlock = np.int32(cols)

bdim = (xBlock, yBlock, 1)
dx, mx = divmod(rows, bdim[0])
dy, my = divmod(cols, bdim[1])
gdim = ( (dx + (mx>0)) * bdim[0], (dy + (my>0)) * bdim[1])
print "bdim=",bdim, ", gdim=", gdim

func(a_gpu, b, block=bdim, grid=gdim)
a_doubled = np.empty_like(a)
cuda.memcpy_dtoh(a_doubled, a_gpu)
print a_doubled - 2*a
```

The code should print the block dimensions `bdim` and the grid dimensions `gdim`, as well as an array of zeroes.

This works for small array sizes, for example, if `rows=256` and `cols=10` (as in the example above) the output is as follows:

```
bdim= (4, 10, 1) , gdim= (256, 10)
[[ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
 ..., 
 [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]]
```

However, if I increase `rows=512`, I get the following output:

```
bdim= (2, 10, 1) , gdim= (512, 10)
[[ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
 ..., 
 [ 2.  2.  2. ...,  2.  2.  2.]
 [ 2.  2.  2. ...,  2.  2.  2.]
 [ 2.  2.  2. ...,  2.  2.  2.]]
```

Indicating that the multiplication is happening twice for some elements of the array.

However, if I force the block dimensions to `bdim = (1,1,1)`, the problem no longer occurs and I get the following (correct) output for the larger array size:

```
bdim= (1, 1, 1) , gdim= (512, 10)
[[ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
 ..., 
 [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]]
```

I don't understand this. What is happening here which means that this method of defining the block and grid dimensions is no longer appropriate as the array size is increased? Also, if block has dimensions (1,1,1) does this mean that the calculation is being performed serially?

Thanks in advance for any pointers and help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You operate on 2D grid of 2D blocks. In your kernel you seem to assume that `gridDim.x` would return number of threads in `x` dimension of a grid.

```
__global__ void MatMult(float *a, float b)
{
    const int i = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x * blockIdx.x;
    const int j = threadIdx.y + blockDim.y * blockIdx.y;
    int Idx = i + j*gridDim.x;
    a[Idx] *= b;
}
```

The `gridDim.x` returns number of blocks r `x` direction of grid, not number of threads. In order to obtain number of threads in given direction you should multiply number of threads in a block with number of blocks in a grid in the same direction:

`int Idx = i + j * blockDim.x * gridDim.x`

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I suppose my next question would be: Is there a way to generalise this for all array shapes? The solution that you have given above is very helpful and has allowed me to use larger arrays, but I still run into the same issues if I keep increasing array size.

Also, are the threads within each block run in parallel whilst each block is run serially, or is it that each block within the grid is run in parallel? For example, would a block shape of (1,1,1) cause the calculation to be done serially?

Comment: Glad I could help, @FeeJF. I would recommend you reading [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9985912/how-do-i-choose-grid-and-block-dimensions-for-cuda-kernels) and [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10460742/how-do-cuda-blocks-warps-threads-map-onto-cuda-cores) and applying it to your solution.

Comment: Excellent, thanks a lot. Along with the links I should be able to make a decent amount of headway and begin to understand what I'm doing here!